# Sublime Text 3 functions helper

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sublimetext3

I'm new to Sublime Text, coming there for a little of PHPStorm and a lot of PHPdesigner. I'm very amazed of the capabilities of Sublime, but here is something I miss. In those editors, when starting typing a function (let's say preg_match in PHP, for example) a little title window shows up which contains a brief description of what the function is for, her args, the return value...

It does this for every functions in PHP, JS, Jquery and more. I couldn't find an equivalent plugin in Sublime.

Thanks ahead for your help !

Comment: You mean autocomplete? Try "Ctrl+Space"

Comment: Nope, I mean helper title window. Look here : http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-rJufV1L2gOE/TcWwe3K3KMI/AAAAAAAAADc/npw8RzYpxBE/s1600/89aac2e7.png there is a helper window on the explode function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no tool tip API available in ST. That being said, it is a highly requested feature. So in short, what you want is not possible (yet).

It's probably also worth mentioning that ST is a text editor, not an IDE. While plugins such as SublimeCodeIntel, attempt to extend it's functionality to be more IDE like (such as context specific completions), it isn't built into the editor itself. PHPStorm has information about your entire PHP project. In addition, it contains information for built in methods. With all that being said, I'm sure if the API made tool tips (among other things) available, some plugin developer would build in information for methods native to a particular language.